# regular expression to extract multiple formatted values from a string

Tags: string, expression

I'm not a regular expression expert, to say the least. What I'm looking for is a regular expression that extracts multiple values of a certain format from a string.

Example string:
"Customer [record:CustomerID] from [record:CityID] is of type [record:TypeID]"

What I need is an expression that gives me all values in this string that are of the format "[record:XXXXX]". So in this example it would give me:

["CustomerID", "CityID", "TypeID"]

Can it be done?

Comment: Are you using a specific language? You could do what you are after with regular expressions goups, however that depends on the structure you have and language you are using.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
var pattern = '\\[record:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]';
var records = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
var extract = new RegExp(pattern);

var string = "Customer [record:CustomerID] from [record:CityID] is of type [record:TypeID]"

var matches = string.match(records);
console.log(matches);
> [ '[record:CustomerID]',
    '[record:CityID]',
    '[record:TypeID]' ]

var records = [];
for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    var match = matches[i].match(extract);
    records.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(records)
> [ 'CustomerID',
    'CityID',
    'TypeID' ]
```

Possibly not the most concise solution, but clean and (hopefully) intelligible.

- the square brackets that should not be treated specially are escaped by placing `\` in front of them
- the group to be extracted are wrapped in `()`, forming a regexp group/subpattern
- the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` means "match a string of letters (upper or lower case) or numbers" and the `+` specifies "of length one or more". A `*` here would mean "of length 0 or more".

Here I am using two regular expressions, based on the same pattern. They are compiled with different options: the `g` flag tells the regex to look for all matches in the string. With this flag, we don't get the groups that matched with the results, just the whole string that matched. The second regex is compiled without the `g` flag, so we can use it to extract the matched group.

Comment: Not sure if I made myself clear: The example string I gave is the **exact** string I want to use.

Comment: Right. Use the regex in my (updated) example on your string, and it will extract your values into an array.

Comment: @chesles: Just as an FYI, when replying in comments, if you do `@username`, your reply will be shown in `username`'s notifications. This will allow them to respond to any of your comments.

Comment: @chesles: Thank you for your solution which works indeed. However, in order to use your method on any given string containing [record:XXXXX] parts I have to create a regex for that particular string in which I replace the XXXXX by [a-zA-Z0-9]+  . Thus I have to first find the XXXXX parts which was the task I set out for in the first place !

Comment: @KirkOlsen: so, you want to *automatically generate* a regex that will extract those parts? Why didn't you say so? :) I'd have to see what the other inputs look like to get an idea whether that's possible.

Comment: @chesles: I would like a generic regex that I can use on a variety of strings containt [record:XXXXX] parts.
E.g.:
* "Customer [record:Customerid]"    -> regex should return ["Customerid"]
* "City [record:CityID] state [record:StateID]"  -> regex should return ["CityID", "StateID"]
* "Name [record:Name] Gender [record:GenderID]"  -> regex should return ["Name", "GenderID"]

Hope this clearifies things, thanx for thinking with me though!

Comment: @KirkOlson Piece of cake. AFAIK there's not a way to do it using just one regex, but I could very well be wrong. Check out the new, more generic solution.

Comment: @chesles: Thanx! although I was looking for a single regex solution this works like a charm as well!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, something like `sed` may do the trick, i.e.:

```
echo "Customer ..." | sed -e 's/\][^[]*\[record:/","/'g -e 's/^.*record:/["/' -e 's/].*$/"]/
```